# Efficiently use Get-job cmdlet in powershell

Tags: powershell, jobs

I am running jobs on multiple servers , What is the most effective way that the get-job cmdlet can keep producing the results as soon as they are available or completed .
The PROBLEM I am facing that when I try tio access the results some of them are not even completed.hence I get weird data and using remove-jobs kills the job very soon.

get-job | Remove-Job -force is killing the jobs too soon. The target is to get the job results as soon as they are complete and then removed.

```
  $servers = gc .\servers.txt
$arr = @()
foreach ($server in $servers)
    {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Get-StoragePool Storagepool01 | select -Property AllocatedSize ,size } -AsJob
           }

    $noofservers =  get-job | measure
    $details = get-job | Receive-Job
    get-job | Remove-Job -force

    while ($out1 -le $noofservers.Count)
        {
        $out1
                  $details[$out1].PSComputerName
                  $details[$out1].AllocatedSize/1TB
                  $details[$out1].size/1TB
                  $out1++
}
```

Comment: Why do you use jobs here in the first place? `-ComputerName` support specifying multiple computers: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $servers -ScriptBlock {Get-StoragePool Storagepool01 | select -Property AllocatedSize ,size }`.

Comment: @PetSerAl It just takes too much time for each invoke , The idea is to execute jobs on all and collect the results. That way its faster

Comment: `Invoke-Command` already do its work in parallel. If default throttle limit (32) is to small for you, than you can specify your own `-ThrottleLimit ([int]::MaxValue)`.

Comment: Do `$Jobs = Invoke-command <args>` and then `While(get-job $jobs -state running){Wait-Job $Jobs -any|get-job}`